# How to make a good integration of wordpress with a SCM?

Tags: wordpress, git, svn, version-control

I currently have three of the classic environments (dev, staging and prod) setup and running wordpress each one of them. The question that has been bugging me for a while is that how do you keep track of the changes made in the front end if the person making the changes either doesn't know about any SCM or doesn't have access to the back end of the server so we can have a way to track all the changes made to the front end?

So, for example my current setup looks like this:

SCM -> Dev -> Staging -> Prod

Any changes that I made to the code in the repository I check them into source control, so then I can later pull the new changes on our dev environment and see if the changes I made were good. However, if a front-end developer makes changes into the Wordpress installation on Dev, how do you usually keep track of those changes or check them into source control?

One idea was to run a cron job every day looking for new changes on our Dev environment and then if there are any changes, check them into our SCM, but if one day a front end developer makes changes on the front end and then the same day I make changes to the source control then I pull the new changes on Dev, those changes made by the front end developer will be lost.

So, I don't have any other idea of how people that work with CMS like wordpress or joomla, do this. If anyone out there would like to share your setup, would be great.

Thank you!